# express checkout integration step 3 - http redirect

Tags: php, redirect, paypal

here's my question.

I've made a request to the PayPal server to obtain a token but now i don't know how to use it to pass it to the url in which i have to be redirected, and i don't understood in the documentation how this process works.

```
<form method="post" action="https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp">
    <input type="hidden" name="USER" value="user"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="PWD" value="pass"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="SIGNATURE" value="signature"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="VERSION" value="72.0"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTACTION" value="Sale"/>    
    <input name="AMT" value="19.95"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="RETURNURL" value="http://www.example.it"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="CANCELURL" value="http://www.example.it"/><br/><br/>
    <button style="background:#FFF; border:0px;" type="submit" name="METHOD" value="SetExpressCheckout"><img src="https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/GB/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" value="SexExpressCheckout"></button>
</form>
```

In this case i send the data to the PayPal Sandbox server, i'm redirected there and there is the string in output with the token and the "Success" state.

Now i don't understand:

How can i be redirected to the login payment page (with the token inside the querystring) without landing on the Sandbox server url page?

I've watched the PHP SDK example about it but i possibly wanted to use a simple solution like described in the documentation.

Any tips to follow?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Download the **PHP sample implementation** (honestly, it's a package containing sample implementations for Java, .NET, PHP and maybe others) and see, how it is all done. It is really simple to *Copy + Paste* it to Your project.

Comment: Ok, so is that the only way to make the express payment? I've checked that yet. Thanks.

Comment: For sure it is not the **only way**, but the **simplest way**... And there is also an implementation using objects which is very handy nowadays in all the MVC stuff... What is Your issue with this examples? If You do not want to use the example directly from PayPal, then from who?

Comment: Shaddyyx, thanks. I'm using them.